# Access object instances created by functions in PHP

Tags: php, oop, function

I am just getting into OOP PHP but have got a little stuck.

Basically i want to create a function to create the objects, the issue is i can't then access the objects outside of the function:

```
$website0 = new website(0,'test','NameTest');
echo $website0 ->getProperty('name');
```

This works. However:

```
createWebsitesFromDatabase();
echo $website0 ->getProperty('name');

function createWebsitesFromDatabase() {
    $website0 = new website (0,'test','NameTest');
}
```

does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function createWebsitesFromDatabase() {
   global $website0; // here is the trick
   $website0 = new website (0,'test','NameTest');
}

createWebsitesFromDatabase();    
echo $website0 ->getProperty('name');
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign the created object to a variable outside the function by using a return value, that's better than using global in most cases.

```
<?php
   function createWebsitesFromDatabase(){
       $insideVar = new website(0, 'test', 'NameTest');
       return $insideVar;
   }

   $website0 = createWebsitesFromDatabase();
   echo $website0->getProperty('name');
?>
```

Comment: This is much better than the use of `global`.

Comment: Note, though, that the name is createWebSite**s**FromDatabase.  If the name is accurate, you might want to return an array of websites.

Comment: Good point, but the whole code is a very short excerpt, hard to tell a lot about the planned functionality

Comment: Why is it better then using global? the plan is to read in from a database and create objects from each entry - in the end i want a static function within the class itself to generate these to keep it self contained

Comment: Like Nicolas Brown I would like to point you to http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php
By using global you make the var available in scopes, you probably don't need the variable. If you want to keep it self contained, global is the exact opposit of what you want to do.
Like cHao said, you might want to return an array though, instead of using $website0, $website1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
function createWebsitesFromDatabase() {
global $website0;
$website0 = new website (0,'test','NameTest');
}
```

this link should clarify your problem

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php